# In an effort to fight my homosexual tendencies, I have been inserting a tampon in my anus; is this haram?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, homosexuality

I am a gay Muslim and I am fighting my tendencies. To restrict men accessing my anus, I have been inserting a tampon. Is this haram?

Comment: It is good that you are fighting the illegal desire and trying to improve yourself! But why is there a need to do such a thing, it's not like you are bare infront of men that they would do such things and are you always in that state ? If so that is not correct! And you need to be clean of every dirt and impurities to worship Allah in any way of worshipping.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, my God. At the first stage, it would be significant to know regarding the major sin of Lavat. In truth, it is counted as the worst sins. And it is mentioned as a major sin based on the Quran and hadiths. In the meantime it is declared that its punishment is more than Zina. For instance look at the following verses of the holy Quran:

> لتَأْتُونَ الْفاحِشَهَ ما سَبَقَکُمْ بِها مِنْ أَحَدٍ مِنَ الْعالَمِین
>   / عنکبوت، ۲۸٫
>
> And [mention] Lot, when he said to his people, "Indeed, you commit
>   such immorality as no one has preceded you with from among the worlds.
>   (28)
>
> إِنَّکُمْ لَتَأْتُونَ الرِّجالَ شَهْوَهً مِنْ دُونِ النِّساء بَلْ
>   أَنْتُمْ قَوْمٌ مُسْرِفُونَ. / نمل، ۵۵٫
>
> Do you indeed approach men with desire instead of women? Rather, you
>   are a people behaving ignorantly." (55)
>
> [http://tanzil.net](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/27:55)

At the second stage, in regard to what you explained “… I have been inserting a tampon …”, at least it is good that it is important for you that you are endeavoring to avoid … (although it could be haram if it is harmful for your body), but you should pay heed that the punishment of this awful act (although without dokhul could be so larger than inserting a tampon. Consequently the best solution is endeavoring to avoid being a gay. Since according to Shia (and p think Sunni too) it is considered as a major sin with an awful Had.
I suggest you to read the following tradition regarding that:

> Imam Reza (a.s.):
>
> «وَاعْلَمْ انَّ حُرْمَةَ الدُّبُرِ اعْظَمُ مِنْ حُرْمَةِ الْفَرْجِ
>   لِانَّ اللَّهَ اهْلَکَ امَّةً بِحُرْمَةِ الدُّبُرِ وَ لَمْ یُهْلِکْ
>   احَداً بِحُرْمَةِ الْفَرْجِ
>
> Imam Sadiq (a.s.):
>
> That will be Akhar-al-Zaman (end of the world) when “men to men” and
>   “women to women” would be satisfied. (lavat …)

In the meantime it is declared that the Hormat (being haram) of Lavat is more than Zina (as Imam Sadiq (a.s.) said such tradition as well). Besides, it is said that in such situation as you are, it is wajib for you to get married in order to leaving such haram act.

---

On the other hand, don’t forget that it is declared that its Had is 100 lash (knout), and even it is said that the punishment of killing would be for that if sb repeat it three or for times. [www.wikifeqh.ir](http://www.wikifeqh.ir/%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%AE%DB%8C%D8%B0) and [this](http://www.wikifeqh.ir/%D9%84%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B7)

---

Moreover, I strongly recommend you to read the links below as two related helpful issues.

[www.islamquest.net (1)](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa3440) 
/
[www.islamquest.net (2)](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa2331)

---

**Reference:**

- [http://islampedia.ir](http://islampedia.ir/fa/1390/10/%D9%84%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B7-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D9%82%D8%B1%D8%A2%D9%86/)
- [www.wikifeqh.ir](http://www.wikifeqh.ir/%D9%84%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B7)
- and [tanzil.net](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/27:55)

---